# Multiple drawimage() on context produces a memory leak

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am doing multiple `drawImage()` to a canvas from an array of `Image` object. In Firefox, this leads to a huge memory leak after a few dozens of drawImage calls with different images, the process can take up to 1 or 2gb of Ram.

The canvas and the images dimensions are about 1080x608

Basically, my code looks like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var images = [...]; // Array of loaded image (new Image())
var currentImage = 0;


var interval = setInterval(function() {

    context.drawImage(images[currentImage]);
    currentImage++;

}, 50);
```

When I clear the interval, memory consumption goes back to normal after a few minute. And when I remove the `<canvas>` from the DOM, memory consumption stays the same.

Behavior is different in Chrome or Safari, I suspect it to be how garbage collector works in Firefox, is there a way to clear canvas cache memory or something ?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KeitIG/aw1hn93z/1/)

Comment: context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: How big is the images array?

Comment: @grillcsirke: it does not purge memory.

Comment: @Prinzhorn: about 300 images, pretty big, but while the interval is not active, the memory consumption does not increase: it only increases while drawing into the canvas

Comment: You're trying to draw a large image every 50 milliseconds. It's no surprise that you're running out of memory. You're going to need to clear the context, at the very least here, every tick of the loop.

Comment: @ManoDestra: clearing context is not enough, I added a JSFiddle you can see by yourself the memory consumption

Comment: My guess is it has _nothing_ to do with canvas at all. Firefox seems to keep the decoded images in memory after use instead of just the jpegs. 300 * 1080 * 608 * 4 = 751MB RAM. Maybe warm up the cache once and then re fetch them as needed. Or only buffer the once you'll need soon.

Comment: Do you get any problem with this memory consumption? If there is still room, you may be happy that it uses it well instead of GC kicking what you may need in a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah, on my machine, Firefox 45.0.1 ramps up from about 500 Mb to 1500 Mb after the preloading of your 370 images. Assuming they're all the same size of approx 30K, then this seems far larger, but who knows what Firefox is doing here. 370 images is certainly a lot to preload. You could just preload a lower subset and do additional preloads after a certain threshold or something, but of course that takes away from the smooth scrolling movement you're aiming for here. Firefox can be bizarre in its memory consumption at times. There were known memory leak issues that I'm not sure are fixed yet.

Comment: Maybe the garbage collector is not triggering sufficiently fast -- As an experiment could you check what happens if your timer is every 1 second instead every 50ms?

Comment: Don't use setInterval -- it will cause stack failures if it is over-burdened.  Instead use `requestAnimationFrame`. **My snarky comment:** *If you place an elephant on your computer you can't then wonder why your computer operates poorly.* Perhaps transcode your 370 images into a video stream and display it inside a video element. The video element will control preloading and buffering in a resource efficient way that you can't do manually. You can control the playback rate if your design requires slower play rates.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running your code in a test harness and making some changes. The issue, as far as I can tell, is regarding the resultant image that is rendered to the canvas. Despite the image that you load being of fairly low image file size, the resultant image is still 1280 x 720. Even if I change the canvas size and amend your drawImage call to be like this...

```
context.drawImage(
    images[currentFrame],
    0, 0, images[currentFrame].width, images[currentFrame].height,
    0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

... it results in the same 1280 x 720 image, that I can then save from Firefox, and it takes up almost 1 Mb per image, rather than the original 30K or so. And the memory ramps up accordingly every time that drawImage is called with an image that hasn't been drawn before.

So, given that each image is held in memory by Firefox, this results in 370 * 900K approx, which is 328 Mb. Not sure what else is being ramped up here, but the issue is largely one of image conversion. Several 1280x720 images of far larger memory size than their compressed file format are being stored by Firefox, hence the huge leap in memory allocation.

I even moved the context grab inside of the event handler and it had no effect on memory allocation.

Ignore the part below where I load the images and set the images based on the onload event. That can result in images out of sequence. I was just trying that to see if there were any issues there regarding images not being fully preloaded.

```
            var canvas = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
            var canvasProperties = {
                x: canvas.offsetWidth,
                y: canvas.offsetHeight
            };

            var images = [];
            var imagesRange = [0, 369];
            for (var i = imagesRange[0]; i <= imagesRange[1]; i++) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function(event) {
                    images.push(event.target);
                };
                image.src = 'http://frames.teleport.ninja/frames/electrosanne/lowres1080/frame'
                        + parseId(i) + '.jpg';
            }

            var currentFrame = 0;

            canvas.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.deltaY < 0 && currentFrame > imagesRange[0]) {
                    currentFrame--;
                } else if (e.deltaY > 0 && currentFrame < imagesRange[1]) {
                    currentFrame++;
                }

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.drawImage(
                    images[currentFrame],
                    0, 0, images[currentFrame].width, images[currentFrame].height,
                    0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            });
```